# TryParse in if condition

Tags: c#

I'm Getting a querystring data in ASP.NET C# and I need both its string value and int.Parse value of it (if it can be parsed). (in the example I'm skipping checking for null values as it has no effect on my question)

```
value = Request.QueryString["value"];
id = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value"], out id)
```

the code above does what I need but I just got curious if I could write it in one sentence so I tried this:

```
if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value"], out id))) value=Request.QueryString["value"];
```

in this case I don't get the string value if it can't be parsed but I will get Its parsed value.

Any suggestions? I don't have a problem with my code I'm just asking out of curiosity that if it can be done in single line of code.

Comment: A `TryParse` is pretty much designed to go in an `if` condition as it returns `bool`. Your example of assigning `TryParse` to the `id` value is nonsensical. Do not chase the single-line / compressed code fallacy. Make your code readable and understandable to the next developer, the one who has to fix your code.

Comment: this shouldn't work.. int.TryParse returns a bool the first code section makes no sense to me

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but your two sets of code don't make sense as "alternatives", plus TryParse returns a bool, so why assign it to id, which also gets your value...?

Comment: Isn't the `out id` parameter use less? you are already assigning the value to `id`??

Comment: You're strongly violating the Single-Responsibility Principle with this one...

Comment: well I need string value anyway but if the value is an integer I need to use it as a database entry. just skip my examples. I was just curious to know if I can get both string value and parsed value in single line of code.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani A better question would be: why do you feel the need to achieve that? It has no functional bearing on the code whatsoever and will likely make it harder to read. Work on the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) when it comes to what your code looks like.

Comment: Technically speaking, you can do anything in one line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *almost*-one-liner version would be

```
// id and value still need to be defined, of course!
int.TryParse(value = Request.QueryString["value"], out id)
```

Your code *shouldn't* work: if `id` is an `int` it won't be able to hold the `bool` coming out from `TryParse`.

Comment: Althought you're right, I can't resist to point out that your code would be such a fun to debug if something went wrong in that module and you'd have to find a reason :)

Comment: I didn't mention the fact that I would *never* write code in this fashion and strongly advise against this style... but OP asked for a one-liner, so here it is.

Answer (score 5):

Inline output variables are supported with C# 7.0 (released back in March '17)

```
var value = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value"], out int id) ? Request.QueryString["value"] : null;
```

id (output variable) will contain the parsed value or default(int)

Answer (score 4):

You can this out,

```
 int id;
 string value = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value"], out id)) ? Request.QueryString["value"] : null;
```

Comment: You still need to declare the `id` variable, so it cannot be done on one line.

Comment: well I didn't meant the declarations so this code seems to be what I was looking for

Comment: as mentioned in other answers, with C# 7 you can skip the first line and instead do `out int id`

Answer (score 1):

If we change Alex's answer to use `out int id` we don't even need to declare `id` in a separate line.

```
int.TryParse(value = Request.QueryString["value"], out int id);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not (want) do assignments in conditionals.

Also, if you're assigning it to `value` then you should utilize `value` for efficiency.

```
value = Request.QueryString["value"];
id = int.TryParse(value, out id)
```

Lastly, you sure about `id`?  You're assigning it to the boolean return of TryParse, yet assigning the out to it as well.  I think your code is incorrect, though you say it is good.

I would assume you mean to do this:

```
var value = Request.QueryString["value"];
int id = -1;
if(int.TryParse(value, out id))
     /* Do work here */
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare it all on one line, but if you have multiple int variables you could delclare them all on one line.

**Note:** if int.TryParse fails is actually sets the out parameter to 0, with out parameters it needs to be assigned before leaving the method so I guess this is why.

eg:

```
private void test()
{
    int id, id2, id3 = int.MinValue;

    string value1 = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value1"].ToString(), out id) ? Request.QueryString["value1"].ToString() : null;
    string value2 = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value2"].ToString(), out id2) ? Request.QueryString["value2"].ToString() : null;
    string value3 = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["value3"].ToString(), out id3) ? Request.QueryString["value3"].ToString() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like my own personal example for others who may need it with null checking and returning both a string and a conversion.  You could move the local string variable out if you needed to.

```
        //Sets nUnitPrice to 0 if the value entered is not a double.  If null remains 0.00.
        if (dgvQuote[colUnitPrice.Index, nRow].Value != null)
        {
            var unitPriceSubString = dgvQuote[colUnitPrice.Index, nRow].Value.ToString().Replace("$", "").Trim();//Substring local variables reduce the number of times substringing needs to be called.
            nUnitPrice = double.TryParse(unitPriceSubString, out _) 
                ? Convert.ToDouble(unitPriceSubString) 
                : 0.00;
        }
```